# Implementing a custom convolution operation in Tensoflow/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to create a convolutional layer that goes over an array with a window, grabs the highest and lowest values and returns a value inversely proportional to the range.

This is the code I'm using presently, but I don't think the operation is applying the way I expect.

```
class StandardizedConv2DWithOverride(layers.Conv2D):
    def convolution_op(self, inputs, kernel):
        ranger = np.ptp(kernel) #this finds the range in the kernel
        return tf.nn.conv2d(
            inputs,
            1/ranger, #This is the inversely proportional value
            padding="VALID",
            strides=list(self.strides),
            name=self.__class__.__name__,
        )
    
conv = StandardizedConv2DWithOverride(filters=1,kernel_size=(5,5))
conv.build(input_shape=(5,5,1))
conv.set_weights([np.ones((5,5,1,1)),np.zeros((1))])
```

This should then ideally go through and highlight the uniform areas of this image

[image]

But instead it seems to just like blur it

[image]

Is there some way of creating such a convolution layer?

Comment: You're trying to do a manual convolution? What is the kernel you're trying to use (you have a "top-hat" in there now which will definitely blur)? If you're trying to learn a kernel, why do you expect it to "sharpen" the image unless specifically trained to do so?

Comment: I read your description again. I don't think you want a convolution, just a windowed nonlinear function, which you can also make a custom version of in keras. Look at maxpool for inspiration -- in fact you could probably build what you want from maxpool.

Comment: You're right, I think maxpool is more what I want. I'll look into that.